# Working with R; error message saying Error in UseMethod("as.quoted")

Tags: r, plyr

trying to take a linear model of an existing data set; "datm"... my code for that one step is

```
 linm_list <- dlply(data = datm, c("well"), function(x) lm(fluorescence ~ elapsed, data=x))
```

and I get an error message saying:

```
Error in UseMethod("as.quoted") : 
 no applicable method for 'as.quoted' applied to an object of class "function"
```

Need help debugging this one line, let me know if having the rest of the code would help.

Comment: The parameter is called `.data`. If you correct that (or use positional matching for this parameter too) it should work.

Comment: It would help having a fully [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), but also describe what exactly you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: sorry meant to thank you earlier, Roland; you were right